# How to store an exception

Tags: java, if-statement, exception

I want to throw an exception and to display it. In my IF block I throw the exception. Do I have to store the exception to pass it as a variable in the method which precedes.

```
if(count !=0) {
  throw new Exception();
  eventLogger.logError("The count is not zero",e)
}
else{
    // do something else
}
```

The logger has Throwable error as a parameter.

```
logError(String description, Throwable error);
```

How can I pass the exception I thrown to this method

Comment: An `Exception` is-a `Throwable`. However, your `logError` invocation is unreachable once you've thrown the `Exception`. Might want to simply invert the statements.

Comment: what is e in eventLogger.logError("The count is not zero",e)  provide some the method implementation and also state what you want to achieve

Comment: I think the main thing here is that OP was not aware of the ability to do `Exception e = new Exception(); log(e); throw e;`

Comment: Note that this will not compile as `eventLogger.logError("The count is not zero",e)` is unreachable.

Comment: I don't get it. why would the OP need an Exception here. I thought Exceptions are things that are not part of the normal program operation and are rather rare.

Comment: @abdul Well if his method is designed to not reach a `count` of `zero` then this could be okay, looks like `IllegalStateException` (or `IllegalArgumentException` if count comes as argument) or even `AssertionError`, depending on the expected behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once the Exception is thrown, your program stops running. Thus you have to change the order of your statements.

```
if(count !=0) {
  Exception e = new Exception();
  eventLogger.logError("The count is not zero",e)
  throw e;
}
else{
    // do something else
}
```

As you can read in the [Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) the class Exception
extends Throwable

**EDIT**

As Zabuza mentioned, it's possible to handle the exception in a try- catch block. This would be a more elegant way:

```
try{
    if(count !=0) {
      throw new Exception();
   }else{
    // do something else
   }
}
catch(Exception e){
  eventLogger.logError("The count is not zero",e)
}
```

Comment: To extend the answer: You can also access the exception object with `try-catch`. So, as alternative, you can also log it at the point where you react to errors instead of the point where it gets thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions don't work like this. Once you `throw` an exception, the code gets interrupted and doesn't run any further. You can access the thrown exception in the next `try-catch` block like this:

```
try{
    //code that may throws an exception like this:
    throw new Exception();
}catch(Exception e){
    eventLogger.logError("Your message", e);
}
```

If you wannt to log the exception **before** you catch it you have to first create it, then log it and finally throw it.

```
Exception e = new Exception();
eventLogger.logError("your message", e);
throw e;
```

Answer (score 1):

The logger will never be reached in your example, as the Exception is thrown a line before. To log an error, you'd do so in the `catch` part of your `try - catch` block

```
try {
    throw new Exception();
} catch (Exception e) {
   eventLogger.logError("The count is not zero",e);
}
```

Comment: It makes no sense to throw the exception inside a try like this.

Comment: Of course it doesn't @puhlen . But it still demonstrates how to log the exception

Answer (score 0):

When you throw an error, you terminate the execution of the method. That makes your second statement unreachable.

In your method header, declare `methodName() throws Exception`. Now, wherever this method is called, you know that there is a risk it may throw an exception.

```
try{
    methodName();
}
catch(Exception e){
    eventLogger.log(e);
}
```

Switching the order will not help you because `e` is not understood.

Answer (score 0):

Exception is throwable so, once `throw new Exception();` is executed then

```
eventLogger.logError("The count is not zero",e)
```

above statement will be come unreachable. So you need to complete all operations(like method calls.. etc.) before throwing an exception. And you should write the exception printing code in a catch clause.

So finally you need to change the code as follows...

```
try{
    if(count !=0) {
     // do method callings
      throw new Exception();
   }else{
    // write alternative flow here
   }
}
catch(Exception exception){
  logger.error(exception);
  eventLogger.logError("The count is not zero",exception);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are doing will throw an exception (e.g. calling File.open() or something) then wrap it in a try-catch-finally

```
bool errorOccurred = false;
try {
    // do things that can cause errors here.    
} catch (Exception e) {
    // things in here happen immediately after an exception in try-block
    eventLogger.logError("The count is not zero", e);
    errorOccurred = true;
} finally {
    // always happens after a try, regaurdless or exception thrown or not
    if (errorOccurred) { 
        /* report error to user or something else */ 
    } else {
        /* finish up */
    }
}
```

but if you just want to log that specific condition was met, you can make your own exception object, and pass it to the error logging method without using try catch

```
if (count != 0) {
    Exception ex = new Exception(); 
    // set the properties you need set on ex here 
    errorLogger.logError("The count is not zero", ex);
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

For the second option, you can use different subclasses the inherit from Exception, or you can even make your own implementation.